# How to write the regex expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

The input string: `A+SUM(A)C+AB-C+SUM(A)+1`

I want to replace A with 0, the result like this:`0+SUM(A)C+AB-C+SUM(A)+1`

or replace SUM(A) with 0,  the result like this:`A+SUM(A)C+AB-C+0+1`

Thanks

Comment: What have you got so far? Stackoverflow isn't really a 'do this for me' set up/

Comment: Do you really need a RegEx for this? Might be easier to just use a String.Replace().

Comment: Well it won't always be A I'd imagine, A could be 2 or 2000000 or 23324897 etc..

Comment: @RyanMcDonough ..that just points out a flaw in this question. There are no details.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question, the previous version was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Without Regex (because Regex is overkill for this):

```
var s = "A+SUM(A)+B-C";

var replaceBeginningA = s.Replace("A+", "0+");
var replaceSumA = s.Replace("SUM(A)", "0");

Console.WriteLine(replaceBeginningA); // 0+SUM(A)+B-C
Console.WriteLine(replaceSumA); // A+0+B-C
```

As pointed out in the comments though, you need to provide more detail if this input is expected to have a different format.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

replace `^A` with `0`

replace `SUM\(A\)` with `0`

Answer (score 0):

Try thus:

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b(\w+)\+SUM\(\1\)", "0+0");
```

This will match anything of the form

```
foo+SUM(foo)
```

and replace it with `0+0`